# Is there a way to disable a legend item by default?

Tags: highcharts

Hi Highcharts community,

I'm curious to know if there is a way to disable a single legend item by default. For example, if there were 3 legend items- "Accepted" "Ideal" "Prediction", is it possible to have ONLY the "Prediction" legend item disabled after the chart loads without having to click on the legend item first? (Note: I don't want to eliminate the legend item altogether, I just want it to be greyed out initially, and still retain the functionality to enable the legend item again after clicking it).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. In the `series` options for the data element you do not want to show set the [`visible`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Cline%3E.visible) property to false.

```
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    visible: false
}, {
    data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
}]
```

Updated to set visibility after load.
To handle the case you talk about where you cannot inject the `visible` series property you can do this in the [`chart.events.load`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) using [`series.update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update):

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function () {
            this.series[0].update({
                visible: false
            });
        }
    }
},
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/huvg47yq/).

In this example I have used the index 0 for Tokyo series. You can do check for other series properties with `if` statements.

Comment: What about in the event that the series options do not specify any data? My plot options/series looks like this, and I'm not sure how to isolate just one legend element. Here's how my series options look:

series: {
        marker: {
               enabled: false,
               states: {
                   hover: {
                       enabled: true
                   }
                }
   },
  connectNulls: true
},

Comment: How are you building your series with data and how are you doing it without? If you have no data why create the series?

Comment: In all honesty I don't have much of an understanding as to how it's working. I am working on existing code which uses an AppSDK that uses highcharts for its chart applications. The only series options that I find all throughout the app code is the one I provided in the comment above (which is not even in the file I am changing) and other ones like this:

series: [ { "as": "Prediction", "field": "To Do"}]

I can modify the "as" parameter and if I change the name to something other than 'Prediction', it actually changes on my chart's legend, but the visible property will not respond here.

Comment: What happens if you add the `visible` property where you change "as"?

Comment: No luck. It has no response whatsoever. However, when I add the visible property to the series options in the first comment, it makes the entire legend bar disabled. Do you know of a way to fetch the data that I want to specifically disable since it doesn't seem to be inserted as 'data' into the series options?

Comment: I have no idea what AppSDK is so I cant help with that. Now, if you know the index of the series you want to disable from being rendered but still show in legend you can look at `chart.events.load` and add a series update to set `visible` property to false.

Comment: Huh, hard one. It looks like some wrapper for Highcharts is involved, which doesn't support `visible` option. And about second solution, I would rather use `series.hide()`, since `series.update()` has much worse performance.

Comment: That worked perfectly @wergeld! Thanks a bunch. I also went ahead and changed that method to `.hide()` instead, so thanks @Pawel Fus

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me,(i am binding dynamic series)

```
 $(Chart.series).each(function (i, val) {
        if (val.name == "All Entity") {
             val.setVisible(true);
        }
   });
```